# Reading binary file using numpy fromfile in combination with lzma open

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, lzma

I have a binary file which contains double values (64bit floating point data). Using numpy `fromfile`

```
>>> data1 = numpy.fromfile(open('myfile', 'rb'))
```

I receive the correct data (I get the same data with `data1 = numpy.fromfile('myfile')`)

```
>>> data1
array([  1.29000000e-07,   3.70000000e-08,   3.80000000e-08,
     3.70000000e-08,   3.60000000e-08,   3.80000000e-08,
     3.80000000e-08,   3.70000000e-08,   3.80000000e-08,
     3.60000000e-08,   3.80000000e-08,   3.70000000e-08,
     3.60000000e-08,   3.60000000e-08,   3.80000000e-08,
     3.50000000e-08,   3.80000000e-08,   3.80000000e-08,
     3.80000000e-08,   3.60000000e-08,   3.70000000e-08,
     3.60000000e-08,   3.70000000e-08,   3.70000000e-08,
     3.60000000e-08,   3.50000000e-08,   3.70000000e-08,
     3.70000000e-08,   3.60000000e-08,   3.50000000e-08,
     3.80000000e-08,   3.80000000e-08,   3.60000000e-08,
     3.50000000e-08,   3.90000000e-08,   3.70000000e-08,
     3.70000000e-08,   3.70000000e-08,   3.50000000e-08,
     3.70000000e-08,   3.60000000e-08,   3.70000000e-08,
     3.80000000e-08,   3.90000000e-08,   3.90000000e-08,
     3.60000000e-08,   3.60000000e-08,   3.70000000e-08,
     3.60000000e-08,   3.80000000e-08,   3.70000000e-08,
     3.50000000e-08,   3.50000000e-08,   3.60000000e-08,
     3.60000000e-08,   3.70000000e-08,   3.50000000e-08,
     3.70000000e-08,   3.60000000e-08,   3.80000000e-08,
     3.80000000e-08,   3.80000000e-08,   3.80000000e-08,
     3.90000000e-08,   3.90000000e-08,   3.50000000e-08,
     3.80000000e-08,   3.80000000e-08,   3.70000000e-08,
     3.70000000e-08,   3.60000000e-08,   3.80000000e-08,
     3.60000000e-08,   3.70000000e-08,   3.70000000e-08,
     3.80000000e-08,   3.60000000e-08,   3.60000000e-08,
     3.50000000e-08,   3.80000000e-08,   3.60000000e-08,
     3.70000000e-08,   3.60000000e-08,   3.80000000e-08,
     3.50000000e-08,   3.80000000e-08,   3.70000000e-08,
     3.60000000e-08,   3.70000000e-08,   3.90000000e-08,
     3.60000000e-08,   3.60000000e-08,   3.90000000e-08,
     3.80000000e-08,   3.60000000e-08,   3.60000000e-08,
     3.70000000e-08,   3.70000000e-08])
```

I now compress this file using `xz`

```
xz -k myfile
```

and subsequently try reading the data in python using the `lzma` module

```
>>> data2 = numpy.fromfile(lzma.open('myfile.xz'))
>>> data2
array([  2.05244522e-289,   3.09873319e-303,  -9.10852154e-136,
     9.99900586e-150,  -7.22647881e+061,  -3.03508634e-168,
     1.40409926e+097,  -8.66961452e+219,   2.28992199e-308,
    -7.28706929e+173,   1.41101250e+029,  -2.94590886e-279,
     7.21680144e+171,  -4.62715868e+045,   3.05536517e-138,
    -2.94268247e-043,  -1.54563603e-295,   7.53024241e+102,
    -1.22865109e+263,   2.62485731e+044,   4.52556260e-312,
     1.18164036e-240,   3.56496646e-311,  -2.82751232e+286,
     1.69336097e+127])
```

Why is this happening? Looking at the content of the file object via `read` gives

```
>>> open('myfile', 'rb').read()
b'B$\xf7\xffgP\x81>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>\x85U\xef\x82\x1e\xf0d>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\x85U\xef\x82\x1e\xf0d>\x85U\xef\x82\x1e\xf0d>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\x85U\xef\x82\x1e\xf0d>\x85U\xef\x82\x1e\xf0d>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\x85U\xef\x82\x1e\xf0d>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\x85U\xef\x82\x1e\xf0d>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>'
>>> lzma.open('myfile.xz').read()
b'B$\xf7\xffgP\x81>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>\x85U\xef\x82\x1e\xf0d>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\x85U\xef\x82\x1e\xf0d>\x85U\xef\x82\x1e\xf0d>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\x85U\xef\x82\x1e\xf0d>\x85U\xef\x82\x1e\xf0d>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\xb3z\xea\x05]\xcab>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\x85U\xef\x82\x1e\xf0d>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\x85U\xef\x82\x1e\xf0d>\xd1\x1e\xae#\xaefd>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>g\xb1+e\xcdSc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>\x1c\xe8l\xc4=\xddc>'
```

which looks good to me. The types seem correct as well:

```
>>> type(data1)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(data1[0])
<class 'numpy.float64'>

>>> type(data2)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(data2[0])
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

I expect the content of arrays `data1` and `data2` to be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I don't know the *why* of the solution but I have one. I generated a file from the [tofile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) method.

I read the compressed version with `frombuffer`.

```
data_xz = np.frombuffer(lzma.open('data.bin.xz', mode='rb').read())
data_bin = np.fromfile('data.bin')
```

and the data is equal upon reading.

My guess is that somewhere, the handling of reading bytes by `np.fromfile` reveals to a difference in the plain read method and the one in the lzma module.

Anyway, storing data is best done using consistent formats. For small data sets, plain text is ok. Else, there is joblib's [persistence module](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/persistence.html) or [HDF5 for Python](http://www.h5py.org/).

Comment: Thank you for the solution/workaround. I would have never tried `frombuffer`.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you :-) I thought of that as the underlying data was bytes, but `fromfile` should have done it as well :-/